# Can I perform the same jquery when either form is submitted?

Tags: jquery

I have two forms on my page (almost identical) and I'd like to write some JQuery to do the SAME thing when either forms are submitted.

Is there any way to have an 'OR' id selector? Something like this

```
$("#form1") || $("#form2").submit(function(e) {
.....
});
```

Comment: `$("#form1, #form2").submit()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery selectors are like CSS selectors, so they support the [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) syntax:

```
$("#form1,#form2").submit(function(e) {
.....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `||`. Just use comma like this

```
$("#form1, #form2").submit(function(e) {
   //other script here
});
```